# Sum of disjoint product of sets

Tags: list-manipulation, programming, algorithm

If we have the following sets and we need to apply the Sum of disjoint product property to them, as in the following example:

Take: $$P_1=\{x_1 x_4\}$$
$$P_2=\{x_2 x_5\}$$
$$P_3=\{x_1 x_3 x_5\}$$

```
P1 = {x1 x4};
P2 = {x2 x5};
P3 = {x1 x3 x5};
```

Step1:
$T_1=P_1=x_1 x_4$

```
T1=Times @@ P1
```

Step2:
$P_1-P_2=x_1 x_4$

```
Complement[P1, P2]
```

$T_2=(1-x_1)P_2+x_1(1-x_4)P_2$

How to get $T_2$ programmatically?

Step3:

$$P_1-P_3=x3 x5$$
$$A_1=(1-x_3)P_3$$
$$A_2=x_3(1-x_5)P_3$$

How to get $A_1 and A_2$ programmatically?

$$A_3=P_2-A_1$$
$$A_4=P_2-A_2$$

How to get $A_3 and A_4$ programmatically?

$$T_3=A_3+A_4$$

Step4:

$$S=T_1+T_2+T_3$$
How can these steps be combined into an algorithm for any three sets?

Comment: **P3 = {x1 x3 x5};** do you not need commas between these letters?

Comment: @Nasser It is a multiplied elements

Comment: If P1 is meant to be `P1={x1 * x2}` and not `P1={x1,x2}` then why do you do `T1 = Times @@ P1` ?

Comment: @Nasser I'm trying to apply my math aspect and both cases are correct for me. I have little experience in how to write code. Any hypothesis  P1={x1 * x2} or P1={x1,x2} is correct

Comment: You will need to help us out a bit with your notation.  For example, what does the operator `+` mean? What is $(1-x_1)P_2$? Is `1` the universal set?  Is $x_1$ by itself really mean the singleton set $\{x_1\}$? Is "multiplication" here cartesian product, etc.

Comment: We need a more general description of the algorithm. It's entirely unclear why, for instance, you're computing $x_1P_1 +x_1(1-x_4)P_2$. If we knew things like that, we'd be able to code up the algorithm. But as it is, I can't follow what's going on here. And some things are inconsistent. $P_1 - P_2 = \{x_1,x_4\}$ makes me thing you're doing a difference of sets (as does the following `Complement[P1, P4]`, but then $P_1-P_3$ should be just $\{x_4\}$, but instead you have it as $\{x_3,x_5\}$, so I'm confused.